# Show that $\mathbf{17 \mid 35^{426} + 67^{283}}$

Tags: number-theory

I know how to solve a different problem - showing that 13 divides $3^{n+2}+4^{2n+1}$, which involves simply splitting up the terms until we see it is congruent to $0 (mod13).$

However, in my above problem, the exponents are not in the same format and since the numbers are very big, I'm not sure how to do it, and I don't want to waste time on what I think will be wrong (keep dividing the exponents by 2 many times...? until I prove congruence to 0?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $34=17\cdot 2$ and $68=17\cdot 4$, it follows that
$$ 35^{426}+67^{283}\equiv 1^{426}+(-1)^{283}\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\mod 17 $$

As a general rule, if you want to compute $a^b$ (mod $m$), it can be helpful to reduce $a$ modulo $m$ before worrying about $b$.

Comment: Aha - thank you very much.  I just found another problem like this too, and the method makes perfect sense now.